# Drop duplicates in a subset of columns per row, rowwise, only keeping the first copy, rowwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe, which is over 7 million rows

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2023-02-22', '2023-02-21', '2023-02-23'],
        'x1': ['descx1a', 'descx1b', 'descx1c'],
        'x2': ['ALSFNHF950', 'KLUGUIF615', np.nan],
        'x3': [np.nan, np.nan, 24319.4],
        'x4': [np.nan, np.nan, 24334.15],
        'x5': [np.nan, np.nan, 24040.11],
        'x6': [np.nan, 75.33, 24220.34],
        'x7': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'v': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'y': [404.29, np.nan, np.nan],
        'ay': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'by': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'cy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'gy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'uap': [404.29, 75.33, np.nan],
        'ubp': [404.29, 75.33, np.nan],
        'sf': [np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If there are any duplicates of a number in any of the columns x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,v,y,ay,by,cy,gy,uap,ubp, I want to to delete the duplicates and only keep one copy, either the one in column `x6` or the first column in which the duplicate appears.

In most rows the first copy if there are copies appear in column x6.

The output should look like this,

```
data = {'date': ['2023-02-22', '2023-02-21', '2023-02-23'],
        'x1': ['descx1a', 'descx1b', 'descx1c'],
        'x2': ['ALSFNHF950', 'KLUGUIF615', np.nan],
        'x3': [np.nan, np.nan, 24319.4],
        'x4': [np.nan, np.nan, 24334.15],
        'x5': [np.nan, np.nan, 24040.11],
        'x6': [np.nan, 75.33, 24220.34],
        'x7': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'v': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'y': [404.29, np.nan, np.nan],
        'ay': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'by': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'cy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'gy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'uap': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'ubp': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'sf': [np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]}
```

So far I only figured out,

```
check = ['x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'v', 'y', 'ay', 'by', 'cy', 'gy', 'uap', 'ubp']

df[check] = df[check].where(~df[check].duplicated(), np.nan)
```

But it's wrong.

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
check = ['x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'v', 'y', 'ay', 'by', 'cy', 'gy', 'uap', 'ubp']
df.loc[:, check] = df.loc[:, check].mask(df.loc[:, check].apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1))
print(df)
```