# Drop duplicates in a subset of columns per row, rowwise, only keeping the first copy, rowwise only if there are 3 or more duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is an extension to my previous question, [Drop duplicates in a subset of columns per row, rowwise, only keeping the first copy, rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75550770/drop-duplicates-in-a-subset-of-columns-per-row-rowwise-only-keeping-the-first/75551691#75551691) I also have a similar question here which has a different requirement [Drop duplicates in a subset of columns per row, rowwise, only keeping the first copy, rowwise only if every column has the same duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560915/drop-duplicates-in-a-subset-of-columns-per-row-rowwise-only-keeping-the-first)

I have the following dataframe. (actual one is around 7 million rows)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2023-02-22', '2023-02-21', '2023-02-23'],
        'x1': ['descx1a', 'descx1b', 'descx1c'],
        'x2': ['ALSFNHF950', 'KLUGUIF615', np.nan],
        'x3': [np.nan, np.nan, 24319.4],
        'x4': [np.nan, np.nan, 24334.15],
        'x5': [np.nan, np.nan, 24040.11],
        'x6': [np.nan, 75.51, 24220.34],
        'x7': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'v': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'y': [404.29, np.nan, np.nan],
        'ay': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'by': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'cy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'gy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'uap': [404.29, 75.33, np.nan],
        'ubp': [404.29, 75.33, np.nan],
        'sf': [np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If there are more than 3 or more duplicates of a number in any of the columns x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,v,y,ay,by,cy,gy,uap,ubp, I want to to delete the duplicates and only keep one copy, the first column in which the duplicate appears or the column that I can select if that's possible.

The output should look like this,

```
data = {'date': ['2023-02-22', '2023-02-21', '2023-02-23'],
        'x1': ['descx1a', 'descx1b', 'descx1c'],
        'x2': ['ALSFNHF950', 'KLUGUIF615', np.nan],
        'x3': [np.nan, np.nan, 24319.4],
        'x4': [np.nan, np.nan, 24334.15],
        'x5': [np.nan, np.nan, 24040.11],
        'x6': [np.nan, 75.51, 24220.34],
        'x7': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'v': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'y': [404.29, np.nan, np.nan],
        'ay': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'by': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'cy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'gy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'uap': [np.nan, 75.33, np.nan],
        'ubp': [np.nan, 75.33, np.nan],
        'sf': [np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]}
```

The second row shouldn't be affected because there's only 2 copies of the number.

The previous question had the answer,

```
check = ['x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'v', 'y', 'ay', 'by', 'cy', 'gy', 'uap', 'ubp']
df.loc[:, check] = df.loc[:, check].mask(df.loc[:, check].apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1))
print(df)
```

But if I do that, then one of the 75.33 would be deleted. That's not what I want.

I was thinking maybe I can do a for loop per row and then replace the value but I have over 7 million rows of data. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that duplicate on float values are not ideal, unless you know for sure that your values are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack the data, work with duplicates there and unstack (pivot) back:

```
s = df.iloc[:,3:].stack().reset_index(name='value')
groups = s.groupby(['level_0','value'])
counts, cumcounts = groups['value'].transform('size'), groups.cumcount()

# verify your condition here - logic might not work as expected
s.loc[counts.ge(3) & (s['level_1'].eq('x6') | (s['level_1'].ne('x6') & cumcounts.gt(0))), 'value'] = np.nan
out = s.pivot(*s).reindex(columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```