# Drop duplicates in a subset of columns per row, rowwise, only keeping the first copy, rowwise only if every column has the same duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is another extension to my previous questions, [Drop duplicates in a subset of columns per row, rowwise, only keeping the first copy, rowwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75550770/drop-duplicates-in-a-subset-of-columns-per-row-rowwise-only-keeping-the-first/75551691#75551691) and [Drop duplicates in a subset of columns per row, rowwise, only keeping the first copy, rowwise only if there are 3 or more duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560780/drop-duplicates-in-a-subset-of-columns-per-row-rowwise-only-keeping-the-first)

I have the following dataframe, (actually its around 7 million rows)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2023-02-22', '2023-02-21', '2023-02-23'],
        'x1': ['descx1a', 'descx1b', 'descx1c'],
        'x2': ['ALSFNHF950', 'KLUGUIF615', np.nan],
        'x3': [np.nan, np.nan, 24319.4],
        'x4': [np.nan, np.nan, 24334.15],
        'x5': [np.nan, np.nan, 24040.11],
        'x6': [404.29, 75.21, 24220.34],
        'x7': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'v': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'y': [404.29, 75.33, np.nan],
        'ay': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'by': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'cy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'gy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'uap': [404.29, 75.33, np.nan],
        'ubp': [404.29, 75.33, np.nan],
        'sf': [np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If there are all duplicates in my selection of columns, I want to to delete the duplicates and keep only 1 copy, if and only if every item in the selection is a duplicate.

Meaning if my selection has 4 columns, all 4 columns must have the same number for it to be considered a duplicate.

If only 2 or 3 of the selection of 4 have duplicates it does not count.

So in my example above, if my selection is, `['x6', 'y', 'uap', 'ubp']`,the output should be,

```
data = {'date': ['2023-02-22', '2023-02-21', '2023-02-23'],
        'x1': ['descx1a', 'descx1b', 'descx1c'],
        'x2': ['ALSFNHF950', 'KLUGUIF615', np.nan],
        'x3': [np.nan, np.nan, 24319.4],
        'x4': [np.nan, np.nan, 24334.15],
        'x5': [np.nan, np.nan, 24040.11],
        'x6': [404.29, 75.21, 24220.34],
        'x7': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'v': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'y': [np.nan, 75.33, np.nan],
        'ay': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'by': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'cy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'gy': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'uap': [np.nan, 75.33, np.nan],
        'ubp': [np.nan, 75.33, np.nan],
        'sf': [np.nan, 2.0, np.nan]}
```

The second row should not be touched because one of the columns are different.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why in your output dataframe, the 75.33 are not NaN even if 75.33 is repeated in y, uap, ubp?

Comment: Or is it that your x6 is actually 404.29 in the first row? and because all 4 values are 404.29 you keep only the first one?

Comment: Yes very true, the logic is unclear. It looks like "any duplicate" might rather be "all duplicates"

Comment: sorry it was a typo, and i mean all duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match all duplicates you can use:

```
selection = ['x6', 'y', 'uap', 'ubp']

# compare all values to the first one
m = df[selection].eq(df[selection[0]], axis=0)

# if all are duplicates, mask them except the first
df.loc[m.all(axis=1), selection[1:]] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
         date       x1          x2       x3        x4        x5        x6  x7   v      y  ay  by  cy  gy    uap    ubp   sf
0  2023-02-22  descx1a  ALSFNHF950      NaN       NaN       NaN    404.29 NaN NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
1  2023-02-21  descx1b  KLUGUIF615      NaN       NaN       NaN     75.21 NaN NaN  75.33 NaN NaN NaN NaN  75.33  75.33  2.0
2  2023-02-23  descx1c         NaN  24319.4  24334.15  24040.11  24220.34 NaN NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Intermediates:

```
m
     x6      y    uap    ubp
0  True   True   True   True  # all True = duplicate
1  True  False  False  False
2  True  False  False  False

m.all(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

#### precision

Note that if you have floating point values, seemingly identical values might not compare equal. In this case it might be safer to compute the mask with:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.isclose(df[selection], df[[selection[0]]])
```

Comment: can you explain the code a little?

Comment: I just added comments ;)

Comment: always first and neater :)

Comment: thanks! do you mind taking a look at this question too, maybe you can solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560780/drop-duplicates-in-a-subset-of-columns-per-row-rowwise-only-keeping-the-first

Comment: @SomeDude Which one you use to compare to doesn't matter. If you have NaNs it's my assumption that then we consider that the values are not duplicated. If really you want to ignore them you could use `bfill` and mask again afterwards depending on the exact wanted logic.

Comment: @anarchy regarding your other question, have you tested the [answer of Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75560962/16343464)? Seems good to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
selection = ['x6', 'y', 'uap', 'ubp']

#Here you see if all values across the selected columns are same
# if they are same the diff would be 0 in both directions and if you take all across columns it will be the row whose value should only be first value.
m = (df[selection].diff(axis='columns').eq(0) | 
     df[selection].diff(-1, axis='columns').eq(0)).all(1)

# Then select such rows you found by above mask and the columns other than the first one - assign them np.nan
df.loc[m, selection[1:]] = np.nan
```

Comment: can you explain your code a little please thanks!

Comment: Are the comments explanatory?

Comment: yes thanks! i picked the other one but your answer is good too